# Why isn't setTimeout working when I persist the event that I'm using?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

Here is my parent component

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <CoordinatesButton onReceiveCoordinates={ mouseCoordinates => console.log(mouseCoordinates) } />
    <DelayedButton onDelayedClick={ event => console.log(event) } delay={1500} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('global')
```

Now I have two child components. DelayedButton

```
export default class DelayedButton extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.persist()
        setTimeout(this.props.onDelayedClick(e), this.props.delay)
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            DelayedButton
        </button>
      );
    };
};
```

and CoordinatesButton

```
export default class CoordinatesButton extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.props.onReceiveCoordinates([event.clientX, event.clientY])
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            CoordinatesButton
        </button>
      );
    };
};
```

Only `CoordinatesButton` works.

The props for `onDelayedClick`returns an error of `Callback must be a function. Received undefined.` `onDelayedClick={ event => console.log(event) }` is clearly an function, because when I console log it, it logs

```
onDelayedClick(event) {
      return console.log(event);
    }
```

Why is this, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` expects a function as its first argument (read the docs [1]). You are calling your function `this.props.onDelayedClick` in-place, which returns `undefined`, hence you are receiving an error `Callback must be a function. Received undefined.`.

Wrap the `this.props.onDelayedClick(e)` call in a function:

```
setTimeout(() => this.props.onDelayedClick(e), this.props.delay)
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clarifying. But I must ask, why doesn't ```setTimeout(function() {return this.props.onDelayedClick(e)}, this.props.delay)``` work?

Comment: @Donnovan Did you try it? It should also work (the return is not necessary however). I used an arrow function in my answer for brevity.

Comment: Yes it worked when I put it in the way you typed it. But when I didn't use the arrow function, i.e. when my syntax changed from ```setTimeout(() => this.props.onDelayedClick(e), this.props.delay)``` to ```setTimeout(function() {return this.props.onDelayedClick(e)}, this.props.delay)``` it no longer worked. But I notice that when I stored the ```this.props.onDelayedClick``` in a variable and used it in the second case, it worked fine.

Comment: @Donnovan Sorry - I was wrong. I forgot that you need the arrow function to preserve `this`. Using a `function` means `this` is no longer pointing to your class instance, but to the global object.